# Sqlite, i have a date field, doesn't return data

Tags: android, sqlite

I have a to tables, and the field **`_fecha`** is a **TEXT** type colunm, and i consulted several examples and nothing.

```
SELECT mae_movintos._id
      , mae_movintos._fecha
      , mae_movintos._tipo
      , mae_movintos._origen
      , mae_movintos._destino
      , mae_movintos._category
      , mae_movintos._monto
      , mae_movintos._orden
   FROM mae_movintos, mae_cuentas
  WHERE mae_cuentas._id = mae_movintos._id
    AND strftime('%s',mae_movintos._fecha) = strftime('%s','2016-10-10')
```

Comment: return zero records, and i have many records in this date, Could anyone help me please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally managed to make it work, it was a small detail in the JOIN

`SELECT mae_movintos._id
      , mae_movintos._fecha
      , mae_movintos._tipo
      , mae_movintos._origen
      , mae_movintos._destino
      , mae_movintos._category
      , mae_movintos._monto
      , mae_movintos._orden
   FROM mae_movintos
   JOIN mae_cuentas ON (mae_cuentas._id = mae_movintos._origen)
  WHERE mae_cuentas._usuario = ?
    AND strftime('%s',mae_movintos._fecha) = strftime('%s','2016-10-10')`

the error is that i had the following:

`JOIN mae_cuentas ON (mae_cuentas._id = mae_movintos._id )`

it was resolved by changing the reference:

`JOIN mae_cuentas ON (mae_cuentas._id = mae_movintos._origen )`

Answer (score 0):

You need to use JOIN if you want to query two tables.

SELECT _id
      , _fecha
      , _tipo
      ,_origen
      , _destino
      , _category
      , _monto
      , _orden
FROM mae_movintos 
JOIN mae_cuentas ON mae_cuentas._id = mae_movintos._id
AND strftime('%s',mae_movintos._fecha) = strftime('%s','2016-10-10')

Comment: didn't work, the error remains, but thanks for your answer